# .htaccess, неявный редирект, поддомены

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго времени суток!

Есть файл .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} .
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/folder/%1\.html [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Эти 4 строчки отвечают за перенаправление с поддоменного адреса, на полный, т.е.:
идем по ссылке sub.domain.com - нас кидает на domain.com/folder/sub.html

Все работает нормально, только преобразование url в браузере происходит явное: проще говоря, sub.domain.com меняется на domain.com/folder/sub.html в адресной строке.

А нужно, чтоб редирект был на стороне сервера, т.е. url в браузере остается
sub.domain.com, но, на самом деле, мы находимся по адресу domain.com/folder/sub.html

Помогите, кто чем сможет, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/folder/%1\.html [R=301,L,QSA]
```

замени на

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/folder/%1\.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Попробовал, все равно в адресной строке url меняется.